# Returning a double variable while apending it using C#

Tags: c#, oop

I am getting some unexpected behavior when trying to return a double into an object data member.

For example:

```
// obj.doubPoints = .25 before operation
obj.doubPoints += SomeFunction(someVar);
// SomeFunction(someVar) returns a 0, and instead it stores the value into obj.doubPoints
// So obj.doubPoints = 0, instead of the expected 0.25
```

I know the easy solution is :

```
double storePoints = SomeFunction(someVar);
obj.doubPoints += storePoints;
// obj.doubPoints = 0.25 afterwards
```

But I am just curious as to why it works that way?

EDIT: I hope this clears it up. This is a more accurate depiction of what is happening.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Temp();
        obj.doubPoints = 0;
        obj.doubPoints += obj.SomeFunction();
    }
}

public class Temp
{
    public double doubPoints = 0;

    public double SomeFunction()
    {
        doubPoints = 0.25;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoa, that's a good way of confusing yourself.

```
obj.doubPoints += obj.SomeFunction();
```

Will be expanded into:

```
obj.doubPoints = obj.doubPoints + obj.SomeFunction();
```

So, when evaluating that expression, it reads `obj.doubPoints` and gets 0. Then it calls `obj.SomeFunction` and gets another zero. Even though the method changes `doubPoints` to .25, that will be after it has been read in the expression. So you still get `obj.doubPoints = 0 + 0`.

Edit: And yeah, as ClickRick has mentioned, this (most likely) isn't guaranteed behaviour. Stay away from things like that!

Edit 2: After some research by ClickRick, it turns out this actually is guaranteed behaviour in C#. In C++, not so much. Good to know!

Comment: ***Sometimes***, yes. The compiler could equally do the RHS evaluation first and then get the LHS, so the result need not be deterministic, depending on optimisations.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx has the pertinent information, in note 2 "The compiler is free to evaluate such expressions in any order", though the qualifier to that then suggests that it might *possibly* be guaranteed after all. Paging Mr Lippert...

Comment: Thanks again ClickRick, I wasn't really taught about this pitfall in school so it is good to know.

Comment: @user3081457 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx is one of Eric Lippert's blogs on exactly this subject. It makes clear that the behaviour is well-defined.

Answer (score 3):

Well, bottom line is that it doesn't work that way.

```
void Main()
{
    var obj = new Temp();
    obj.Dump();
    obj.doubPoints += SomeFunction();
    obj.Dump();
}

public double SomeFunction()
{
    return 0;
}

public class Temp
{
   public double doubPoints = .25;
}
```

Both result in .25.  Something is going on with your inputs, or your outputs, or something... I know, not very useful.

Comment: If I added values to doubPoints within the SomeFunction(), would that change the circumstance?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to increment obj.doubPoints by 0.25 then SomeFunction should do this:

```
public double SomeFunction()
{
    return 0.25;
}
```

Also it might be easier to do this:

```
public double SomeFunction()
{
    doubPoints += 0.25;
}
```

That way instead of saying `obj.doubPoints += obj.SomeFunction();` you could just say `obj.SomeFunction();`.

It seems you may be a bit confused as to what return does. This might help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1h3swy84.aspx